# Поиск совпадающих значений и удаления из запроса с помощью MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Есть 2 таблицы в *MySQL*.

первая

```
id 
 1 
 2
 3
 4
 и т.д.
```

Вторая

```
product_id 
 2 
 4
и т.д.
```

Если совпали `id` из одной таблицы и `product_id` из второй, то этот id не должен попадать в выборку из первой таблицы.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_a a               -- Выбираем все из table_a
LEFT JOIN products p         -- Ищем соответствующую строку в products
   ON a.id = p.product_id    --  (но не выкидываем строки table_a без соответствия)
WHERE p.product_id is null   -- Оставляем только строки без соответствующего продукта.
```

Вообще есть три варианта: JOIN vs NOT EXISTS vs NOT IN, немного отличающиеся семантикой, а также производительностью.

Comment: А как соотносятся производительности?

Comment: Длинное сочинение писать не готов, если короткий ответ, то в MySQL вроде как JOIN лучше: http://phpfaq.ru/where_exists , http://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/03/25/mysql-in-query-performance/ , но это особенность реализации.

Comment: Спасибо. Жестко про where in. А я бы им и воспользовался в подобном случае